# Close 2-Div Modal With Pure JS

Tags: javascript

I have a simple modal which has two divs. I want to have it "close" when either a) hitting esc e.g. keypress key code 27, or b) clicking outside.

I've searched so many posts but so many are js framework specific and/or don't work in the specific situation.

I want to be able to close it on esc or any click outside of the `#emod` div.

Here is what I have:

`<div id="emod-bg"></div><div id="emod"></div>`

CSS

```
#emod-bg 
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #d0d0d0;
    opacity: .50;
    -webkit-opacity: .5;
    -moz-opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: 1000;
}



#emod 
{          
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    height: 480px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -250px 0 0 -160px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 320px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

...and it is activated as follows:

```
    document.getElementById('emod').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('emod-bg').style.display = "block";
```

Comment: jsfiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the modal when hitting the escape key, just add a `keyup` event to the document, and then check the `keyCode` property of the event object.

If you want to close the modal when clicking on the backdrop, just attach a click event and compare `event.target` to `#emod-bg`:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/2jc7funs/)

```
var modal = document.getElementById('emod-bg');
modal.style.display = "block";

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
});

modal.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```